# my emulator does not show the same positioning of views as I design and see while making the app

Tags: android, android-studio

I am using constraint layout and positioning 4 buttons in the middle of the screen in android studio but when I run the emulator. The buttons are shown at the bottom.
I am facing similar kind of problem while using relative layout. Nothing shows on the emulator the way I intend it to. I followed the

I went through the Android developer site to see how they place views in constraint layout. I did the same as instructed. I also went through some posts on Stack Overflow but I was unable to resolve this issue.

Kindly help me. Below is the image describing my problem
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FTxTu.png)

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you have a 'hard'constraint that the top button has to be so many dp from the top of the screen, but the bottom constraint is 'flexible'.  Which means that in order to get the top space to match the hard constraint, on some devices, this might push it further down on the screen.  You could just try deleting the top and bottom constraints, or make them both hard constraints, or both flexible constraints.  I'm not that familiar with constraint editing, so, can't give you specific instructions.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button5"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="Button 5"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="packed"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button4"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button4"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="Button 4"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="packed"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button5"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button2"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="Button 2"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="packed"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button4"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button3"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="Button 3"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="packed"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button2"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: thank you so much.....that gets it in the middle....is it this line that's making it work?->app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="packed"

Comment: anyways, I appreciate your efforts so much. God bless you! :)